# Are addition and multiplication on naturals algebraically distinguishable?

Tags: reference-request, logic

Suppose (N, +) and (N, *) are the structures of addition and multiplication on N, the natural numbers with 0. Let S be the set of equational identities that hold in (N, +), and let T be the set of equational identities that hold in (N, *). Does S=T? If not, is one properly included in the other, and if so, which is included in which? First, some background info. An equational identity, in our context, is one in which only variables appear. The important thing is that we can't mix up the operations, nor can we bring in constants. Also, (x+y)=(y+x) counts as the same identity as (x*y)=(y*x), since switching addition with multiplication results in one transforming into the other. At the very least, I would like a text in which this line of thought is mentioned.

Comment: I suppose you mean to exclude constants in identities?

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, I do.

Comment: How are you defining inclusion here?  The identities include things like (1+1)=2, and (4*4)=16. The structures are not isomorphic since (0*x)=0 as Robert Israel points out.  If the structures get thought of as sets of triples (e. g. in the addition structure they all have the form (x, y, (x+y)), and in the multiplication structure they all have the form (x, y, (x*y))), then we'd probably have to have some way to map between the structures to talk about which one comes as included in the other.  Clearly the structures have the same cardinality, but again they are not isomorphic.

Comment: But 1, 2, 4, and 16 are not in the signature. By equational identity, I mean something an expression with variables, followed by an equation sign, followed by another expression with variables.

Comment: And (x+y)=(y+x) is counted the same identity as (x*y)=(y*x), for simply switching addition with multiplication results in one transforming into the other.

Comment: But the important thing is that we can't have constants, and we can't mix up addition and multiplication.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Could you edit it to add a little background info about the problem, more than just a problem statement?  Even interesting questions that are only problem statements are often put "on hold".

Comment: Can you given an example of an equational identity for $(\mathbf{N},+)$ that is not simply an application of the commutative and associative properties of addition?

Comment: @Blue That is yet another line of inquiry. Whether or not every equational identity in (N, +) can be derived from the commutative and associative identities. Also, the same question can be asked in (N, *). If the answer is yes to both questions, my question is answered in the affirmative.

Comment: @user107952: "If the answer is yes to both questions, my question is answered in the affirmative." That's my point. :)  Well, and I want to verify what you mean by "equational identity". You say "we can't mix up addition and multiplication"; does that mean that the only operation allowed in equational identity on $(\mathbf{N},+)$ is addition? If so, then an expression in equational identity would seem to consist of a collection of variables (allowing repetition) separated by "$+$"s, and possibly grouped by "$()$"s ... wouldn't it? Do you intend "equational identity" to mean something broader?

Comment: @Blue Indeed, the only operation allowed in an equational identity in (N, +) is addition. And the only operation allowed in an equational identity in (N, *) is multiplication.

Comment: @user107952: in that case, isn't the only important factor whether each variable occurs the same number of times on each side of the equation?

Comment: @CarlMummert Prove your claim, then.

Comment: @user107952: By commutativity and associativity of addition, any expression in an "equational identity" on $(\mathbf{N},+)$ with variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $\dots$, $x_n$ (with repetition) can be re-written in the "standard form" $$(x_1+x_1+\cdots+x_1)+(x_2+x_2+\cdots+x_2)+\cdots+(x_n+x_n+\cdots+x_n)$$ where each grouping contains all copies of the corresponding variable, $x_i$. Clearly, two expressions are equal if and only if they have the same "standard form"; therefore, the expressions have the same variables with the same number of repetitions. The same is true for $(\mathbf{N},\times)$.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: @user107952: Good to know! :) I've converted my comment to an official answer. Please accept it to remove this question from the "Unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By commutativity and associativity of addition, any expression in an "equational identity" on $(\mathbf{N},+)$ with variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $\dots$, $x_n$ (with repetition) can be re-written in the "standard form"
$$(x_1+x_1+\cdots+x_1)+(x_2+x_2+\cdots+x_2)+\cdots+(x_n+x_n+\cdots+x_n)$$
where each grouping contains all copies of the corresponding variable, $x_i$.

Clearly, two expressions are equal if and only if they have the same "standard form"; therefore, an equational identity on $(\mathbf{N},+)$ is characterized by its two expressions having the same variables, with the same repetitions. The same is true for $(\mathbf{N},\times)$.

Comment: There is an additional condition used here, I'm not sure how best to phrase the assumption as weakly as it is occurring, but I'll bring up the concern. Let $(G,*)$ be a finite abelian group of order $g$. Then $G$ will satisfy for example: $x^{g+1} = x$, or $x^g = y^g$, basically hidden Lagrange corollaries. Such can't happen in the given structures on $\mathbb{N}$ because generic elements have infinite order.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the cancellation properties of $+$ and $\cdot$ operators on $\mathbb{N}$

If $x+y=z+y$, then we will always have $x=z$.

If, however, $x\cdot y = z\cdot y$, then we may *not* always have $x=z$. (Assuming $0\in \mathbb{N}$)

So, even in isolation from one another, the $+$ and $\cdot$ operators are *not* algebraically indistinguishable in the sense that I think you mean.

Comment: No, there are no conditionals allowed. I allow only equations. At least in the scope of this problem.